# How to add icon for language dropdown in navbarpage in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, navbar, shiny.i18n

I'm working on a R Shiny application and I'm using the navbarPage function to create a navigation bar at the top of my app. Within the navbar, I want to add a dropdown for selecting the language. I would like to enhance the user experience by adding an icon next to the language dropdown to make it more visually appealing. When you click the icon, the user should be able to choose the language.

Here's example code:

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)
i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = "translation.json")
i18n$set_translation_language("English") # here you select the default translation to display
ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),

  navbarPage("My Shiny App",
    tabPanel("Tab 1", 
             mainPanel(
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel (
                   selectInput("selected_language",
                               i18n$t("Change Language"),
                               choices = i18n$get_languages(),
                               selected = i18n$get_key_translation())),
             
                 mainPanel(
                   p(i18n$t("Hello")),
                   htmlOutput("html_output"))))),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    selectInput("selected_language", 
                i18n$t("Change Language"),
                choices = i18n$get_languages(),
                selected = i18n$get_key_translation())))


server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
    shiny.i18n::update_lang(input$selected_language)})


  output$html_output <- renderText({
    i18n$set_translation_language(input$selected_language)})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Here's translation json file
{
"cultural_date_format": "%d-%m-%Y",
"languages": ["English", "Türkçe"],
"translation": [
{"English": "Hello", "Türkçe": "Merhaba"},
{"English": "Change Language", "Türkçe": "Dil Değiştir"}
]
}

I tried to add the dropdown with an icon to navbar (next to tab2) however the dropdown appears in the pages. How can I add the language options to navbar?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example? This question has no direct connection to `shiny.i18n`. Provide an example where you directly write what's currently coming from the `JSON` and delete all `shiny.i18n` parts. Also it would be better if you provide the "I tried ..." part where show your attempts with the icon. What are your requirements for the icon?

Comment: @Jan  This is what I was trying to do. Only difference is that instead of displaying on a page, I tried to implement it into navbar after  "Tab 2" . [Example button](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/blob/main/man/figures/demo.gif)